# php file put contents reverse

Tags: php, file

Ok sorry if its a stupid question im a begginer.

Im making a small shoutbox just for practise.

It inserts the shout infos in a txt file.

My problem is that, it lists the text from top to bottom, and i would like to do this reversed.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
        if(!empty($text)) {
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $time = date("H:i");            
        $content = 
        "<div class='text'><em>" . $time . "</em> 
        <span class='c11'><b>" . "<a href='userinfo_php_willbe_here.php' target='_blank'>" . htmlspecialchars($name) . "</a>" . ":</span></b> 
        " .  htmlspecialchars($text) . " 
        </div>\n";
        file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
}
```

here is my code.

i was googleing around with not much luck maybe i wasnt looking hard enough.

could please someone give me a hint?

thank you

Comment: It does what you tell it to do: it appends the text to what was already in the file. Making it prepend the text is a bad idea, because it would require reading and writing *all* the contents of the file instead of just writing one line.

Comment: you mean to say what ever you append in the file, it will comes to the beginning of file. isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to do so with one function call. You need to read the content from your target file, prepend the data in php and rewrite the whole file (see `file_get_contents`).

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
$fileContent = $content . $fileContent;
file_put_contents($file, $fileContent, LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) like so:

```
// Data in file separated by new-line
$data = explode("\n",file_get_contents("filename.txt"));

foreach(array_reverse($data) as $value) { 
    echo $value."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only **prepend** to a file by means of reading it and writing afterwards.

```
file_put_contents($file, $content . file_get_contents($file), LOCK_EX);
```